# Как в jquery перебрать массив по строковому индексу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример:

```
var arrays = [
        array1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        array2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        array3: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перебрать массив по строковому индексу (array1, array2, array3)?

Comment: в javascript не бывает таких массивов

Comment: а причем тут jquery?

Comment: [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) одинаково работает и с массивами и с объектами

Comment: @vp_arth, никто не мешает добавить массиву строковое свойство. Но да, код в вопросе содержит синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите ещё, как правильнее будет оформить код, если к каждому элементу массива нужно добавить дополнительные данные. т.е. чтобы в одной ячейке содержались двое разных данных? Внутрь массива поместить объекты?

Comment: var arrays = {
    array1: [{'item1', date1}, {'item2', date2}, {'item3', date3}],
    array2: [{'item1', date1}, {'item2', date2}, {'item3', date3}],
    array3: [{'item1', date1}, {'item2', date2}, {'item3', date3}]
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arrays = {
    array1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    array2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    array3: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
};
for (var name in arrays) {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(arrays[name]);
}
```

P.S. Так же у вас в вопросе указан массив которого в JavaScript не существует, должен быть объект, так что скобки заменил на фигурные.

Comment: Укажите еще, что вы поменяли квадратные скобки на фигурные.

Comment: а причем тут _переменные создать в глобальной области видимости_?

Comment: @Grundy действительно не к чему, убрал

Comment: Спасибо! Странно, вчера бился пол дня над этим вопросом и ничего не получалось, а сегодня даже через $.each по index находит. А про то, что js не поддерживает многомерные массивы я что-то слышал, он в интернете много примеров с таким синтаксисом - https://learn.javascript.ru/array#многомерные-массивы

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых не массив, а [объект](https://learn.javascript.ru/object). Соответственно цикл будет выглядеть так:

```js
var arrays = {
        array1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        array2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        array3: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
}

for(var item in arrays) {
  console.log(arrays[item]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Евгений пожалуйста :)